# Building Patch does not include file which was added in previous patch package

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, patch

In patch1 which already shipped, I added a file which did not exist in the original, base package. That worked fine. In patch2, it also worked fine. In patch3 however, this file does not get built into the patch.
Using Orca’s View Patch, I do **not** see the new file ‘added’ into  the File table In the PatchCreation.log when I apply patch3 to the base MSI. In the first two patches however, I see this 'added' entry in the File table as expected.

In the PatchCreatin.log files for the problem patch:
I see two ‘Comparing Files’ entries relating to this file, one for each of the previous uncompressed MSI release builds:

```
INFO Comparing Files: PathTo3.0.1UncompressedMsi\file1.exe PathToLatestUncompressedMsi\file1.exe...
INFO Different sizes...
INFO File Key: file1.exe.e is modified

INFO Comparing Files: PathTo3.0.2UncompressedMsi\file1.exe PathToLatestUncompressedMsi\file1.exe...
INFO Different sizes...
INFO File Key: file1.exe.e is modified
```

With the second patch I built and already released, (again, which worked fine), I see similar logging regarding the comparison of the file in the latest MSI with the file in the first patch MSI:

```
INFO Comparing Files: PathTo3.0.1UncompressedMsi\file1.exe PathToLatestUncompressedMsi\file1.exe...
INFO Different sizes...
INFO File Key: file1.exe.e is modified
```

I’m not sure what the log entries mean as far as what PatchWiz will do about ‘Different sizes’ and ‘is modified’. I would think it means it will include it in the patch. However it is not. **Is it even possible to search for an entry in theses patchwiz logs that confirms something like "ahh, I see you want this in the patch, I will add it"** ??

I also confirmed that the uncompressed MSIs for all of the patches shows, using Installshield's MSI Diff, the file (file1.exe.e) is Added in the File table. So at least that aspect, 
the uncompressed MSI releases which feed into the patch creation, seems to be working as expected.

**Even if we cannot figure out what is going wrong here, is there any other way to 'force' a file into a patch package another way?** Note: I am NOT using 'binary' patches, I am using Include Full File patches

UPDATE: the physical file might actually be in the patch, because when I install the log shows:

```
Note: 1: 2715 2: file1.exe
```

which means

```
The specified File key ('[2]') not found in the File table.
```

So does this mean that makecab put the file in there, however the entries were just never added to the database? And if so, does this mean I can potentially add the appropriate table relationships by hand in the database?

This is confusing, because I see the same entry in the log for the earlier patches I already shipped which DO work fine..

Comment: I think this comes down to whether that file has a file version or not. If it is versioned then the patch tools compare the version in the new build against the base and I'm pretty sure they won't include it if the version is lower. That's because the file versioning rules won't replace the installed file when the patch is applied so there's little point in putting in the patch.

Comment: I've ran into that before, but not this time

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with adding Previous Setup through Installshield IDE. When adding my third previous setup, InstallShield was swapping the value of its Order column with the value of the original setup, thus creating what Microsoft calls an 'uncommon' (I'd say, incorrect..) patch sequence:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372066(v=vs.85).aspx

> Order column: Relative order of the target image. Because multiple
>   targets can be patched to an upgraded image, the Order field provides
>   a means to sequence the transforms in the patch transforms list.
>   Commonly, the order is from oldest to newest image.

Not sure if this is by design by them or not. To fix it, I have to manually edit the .ism file to adjust the order (which is not a very readable schema).